# Adiabatic turn-on of free multi-particle states

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, hilbert-space, s-matrix-theory, adiabatic

Consider a second-quantized operator $\mathcal{H}_{full}$ describing some interacting QFT, whose action is known on a set of Fock states $\{\mathcal{|F\rangle}\}$, which, in turn, are the eigenstates of some free Hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}_{free}$.

If we take a single-particle state $|\mathbf{p}\rangle$ and adiabatically turn on the interaction, this state will become a single-particle state $\widetilde{|\mathbf{p}\rangle}$ in the interacting theory:
$$
U|\mathbf{p}\rangle=\widetilde{|\mathbf{p}\rangle} \, .
$$

**QUESTION**

What is the interpretation of adiabatically turned on multi-particle states of the free theory?
$$
U|\mathbf{p}_1,\mathbf{p}_2\rangle=\,? \,
$$
By construction, those will be the eigenstates of $\mathcal{H}_{full}$ and will have definite energy and momentum. Therefore, they are not multi-particle states of the full theory.

My guess is that such states correspond to excited states of particles / resonances /  scattering states or smth like that.

Comment: This is not an attempt to answer, but just a question: is it really true that $U|{\bf{p}}> = |\tilde{\bf{p}}>$ is a single-particle state? Or is this how we *define* the single-particle states in the perturbed theory?